# Prediction intervals for regressors and how to model uncertainty for predictions

Tags: regression, probability, normal-distribution, standard-deviation

I trained a regression algorithm on data to obtain an estimate for some quantity $x$ in a set of unseen data. lets call the value of one of those test estimates $x_0$.

I would like to model a probability distribution around $x_0$. If I understood correctly, in the case of linear regression I could use the standard error of the response $s_y$  to model a Gaussian distribution $N(x_0, s_y)$ and that's my desired probability distribution for the quantity.

My question is: what if the regression is not linear regression?
My thoughts are:
1) do something similar and calculate the difference of the output of this more general regressor on the data it was trained on to the actual values. -> use this outcome as an estimate for a normal distribution.  Is is correct that only in linear regression the Gaussian distribution with the standard error is correct but for other regressors I'm making a mistake with this approach?
2) calculate the standard deviation of $x$ from the data and use that.

When comparing 2) to 1) in the linear regression case,  isn't that basically the same? I think for the prediction interval (case 1)) you divide the sum of mean squares by $n-2$ and the standard deviation case by $n-1$ but apart from that?

While writing this I see that things are somehow connected, but I'm not seeing it clearly yet.

Comment: what just came to my mind; for a 1) I could do out of fold predicitons and take some rmse of those  OOF predictions as the standard error for  a estimate for a prediction intervall for a generall regressor .

Comment: I've also seen comments to use bagging to estimate the variance and use that as a prediction intervall, but I think there might be better ways

Comment: I think this wiki [https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prediction_interval] has good examples of how to calculate prediction intervals for Gaussian models. In your case I'd think you could use the known mean and known variance variant (as i think you can use the model's estimates). For non-gaussian models of the GLM family (such as logistic regression), you could do the same calculation on the linear predictor before taking the inverse logit (or any other inversed link function).